# How to name / find a specific running python script process on windows?

Tags: python, windows, process, kill, pythonw

**On windows:**

I have two scripts:

1. Client.py
2. Console.py

**Q1:**
Client can be run multiple times but only single instance should be left running.  It is being run with pythonW.exe

**Q2:**
Multiple console.py can be run at the same time. But the last one that closes should kill the client.py

**Limitations:**

1. Strongly preferred not to write any files. (i.e. use search by window name, PID etc...)
2. Strongly preferred not to install any additional modules for python. i.e. use ctypes etc...

For Q1 i tried to do `ctypes.windll.user32.SetWindowTextA ("NAME")` and then search for it. it works for python.exe but not for pythonW.exe beacause there is no console window then.

Thanks!

Comment: You could run the client as a Windows service, then have the console start the service if it not running when it begins, then query the service to check if any other consoles are running when it closes, and stop the service if none are.  There is potential for race conditions and zombies if you aren't careful though...